# How to prepare msgpack to send a struct over a ZeroMQ infrastructure?

Tags: c++, c++11, msgpack

I am trying to communicate between nodes via ZeroMQ. I need to send a `struct` of:

```
struct Content{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> image;
    std::string msg;
};
```

I try to utilize [**`msgpack`**](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c):

```
Content content;
content.image = msg2;
content.mesaj = "naber kardes";

msgpack::type::tuple<Content> src(content);
//                            serialize the object into the buffer.
//                            any classes that implements
//                            write(const char*,size_t) can be a buffer.
std::stringstream buffer;
msgpack::pack(buffer, src);
cout << sizeof(buffer) << endl;
```

but it gives:

> /usr/local/include/msgpack/v1/object.hpp:631:11: error: no member named 'msgpack_pack' in 'Content'

still new to c++.

How can I send my Content struct through ZeroMQ with a help of the `msgpack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a **`pack()`** function for your `Content` struct:

```
namespace msgpack
{
MSGPACK_API_VERSION_NAMESPACE(MSGPACK_DEFAULT_API_NS)
{
namespace adaptor
{

template <>
struct pack<Content> {
    template <typename Stream>
    msgpack::packer<Stream>& operator()(
                msgpack::packer<Stream>& out, Content const& obj) const
    {
        out.pack(obj.image);
        out.pack(obj.msg);
        return out;
    }
};

}
}
}
```

If your software does not evaluate the MessagePack data, you need to create the **pack()** function according to the format/layout expectations of your zmq/MessagePack recipient.

Example of a **convert()** function (same namespace as **pack()** function above):

```
template <>
struct convert<Content> {
    msgpack::object const& operator()(
                msgpack::object const& o, Content& v) const
    {
        // unpack data in the same format as it was packed. see above!     
        return o;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. if you have time Can you kindly complete the example :) to sending the zeromq than deserialize in the other node. Yes asking much but as a Java girl last 2 hour all codes looks like java and starting to confusing lot. it may help also other stucked newbies

Comment: I added the lines to pack obj.image and obj.msg. You need to provide a packer for cv::Mat in the above style, or you can pack the contents of obj.image within the above example. For example packing the length of the vector, followed by N elements of each cv::Mat element.

Comment: Thanks Jens.. I will try and let you know. Some times I thought that there should be a stackoverflow for all Politicians also :) and make should them opensource..