# How to send and get vector<struct> ZeroMQ pub/sub

Tags: c++, vector, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am using zeromq and trying to do a pub/sub socket.
I found examples of how to transfer char* , but I need to know how to transfer a vector from the server, and how to receive it on the client.
I already have a vector<*mystruct*> filled with data. and the transfer of char is organized, but I do not understand how to transfer and receive a vector<*mystruct*>.

I tried to do it like this, at the client:

```
vector<students> inMsg(zmq_msg_size(&reply));
    memcpy(inMsg.data(), zmq_msg_data(&reply), zmq_msg_size(&reply));
```

And like this, at the server, but it doesn't work:

```
zmq_msg_t message;
        zmq_msg_init_data(&message, &vectorData, sizeof(&vectorData), nullptr, NULL);
        zmq_msg_send(&message, publisher, 0);
        zmq_msg_close(&message);
```

I would be very grateful for any hints.
p.s. Sorry for bad English.

Here is a working example with char.
Server-side:

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    printf("Starting server\n");
    int conn = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://127.0.0.1:8080");

    const char* companies[2] = { "Company1", "Company2" };
    int count = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        int price = count % 2;
        int which_company = count % 2;
        int index = strlen(companies[0]);
        char update[12];

        snprintf(update, sizeof update, "%s",
            companies[which_company]);
        Sleep(3000);
        zmq_msg_t message;
        zmq_msg_init_size(&message, index);
        memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&message), update, index);
        zmq_msg_send(&message, publisher, 0);
        zmq_msg_close(&message);
        count++;
    }
    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

Client-side:

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    void* context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void* subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    printf("Collecting stock information from the server.\n");
    int conn = zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://127.0.0.1:8080");
    conn = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        zmq_msg_t reply;
        zmq_msg_init(&reply);
        zmq_msg_recv(&reply, subscriber, 0);
        int length = zmq_msg_size(&reply);
        char* value = (char*)malloc(length*sizeof(char)); //
        memcpy(value, zmq_msg_data(&reply), length);
        zmq_msg_close(&reply);
        printf("%s\n", value);
        free(value);
    }
    zmq_close(subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kate, welcome to SO, in order to pass a struct through the sockets in ZeroMQ, you need first to encode this struct with json, msgpack, or any other data interchange format. Here is a question that can help you to achieve that using msgpack to encode the struct. [How to prepare msgpack to send a struct over a ZeroMQ infrastructure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820032/how-to-prepare-msgpack-to-send-a-struct-over-a-zeromq-infrastructure).

Comment: The general idea is to encode the struct, pass it through the socket. In the other end of the socket, decode this message into the struct and done. You could do this with, json as well.